# Como agregar un href usando jquery

Tags: jquery, html

Estoy tratando de agregar un href a un div tengo el siguiente codigo:

```
<div class="field field-name-field-palabras-clave field-type-text field-label-inline clearfix">
<div class="field-label">Tags:</div>
<div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">libreta
        <div class="icon-more_link"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-item odd">pluma
        <div class="icon-more_link"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

y quiero hacer esto:

```
<div class="field field-name-field-palabras-clave field-type-text field-label-inline clearfix">
<div class="field-label">Tags:</div>
<div class="field-items">
    <div class="field-item even">
        <a hef="search/libreta">libreta</a>
        <div class="icon-more_link"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="field-item odd">
        <a hef="search/pluma">pluma</a>
        <div class="icon-more_link"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

me podrian ayudar porfavor

Comment: Si alguna respuesta te sirvió puedes marcarla como aceptada.

Answer (score 3):

```
var link="www.google.com"
 $('#tuEtiqueta').attr('href', link);
```

Ahí le cambiar o agregar atributo `href` a cualquier elemento que lo necesites

Answer (score 2):

Creo que lo que buscas en una función similar a esto

```
$('.field-item .even').click(function() {
    valor= $(this).html();
    $(this).prepend('<a hef="search/'+valor">'+valor+'</a>');
});
```

Aunque si lo que quieres es que se redireccione la página directamente al pulsar sobre la tag, podrías hacer algo similar a esto

```
$('.field-item .even').click(function() {
    valor= $(this).html();
   $(location).attr('href',"search/"+valor);
});
```

Comment: Puede que quiera eso, pero en principio el `click( ... )` del primer fragmento de código estaría de más. 
Y en el segundo framento has puesto `"search7"`, ¿no debería ser `"search/"`?
Podrías completar tu respuestas con las referencias a las funciones de jQuery que estás utilizando (ej: `clicl()`,`html()`, `attr()` y `$(location)`". Así quién pregunta sabe donde mirar.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la función `prepend`

```
$('.field-item .even').prepend('<a hef="search/libreta">libreta</a>');
$('.field-item .odd').prepend('<a hef="search/pluma">pluma</a>');
```

más info en [jquery prepend](http://api.jquery.com/prepend/)

Comment: gracias solo que no se que valor este en la etiqueta field-item.even o field-item.odd hay alguna forma de obtenerlo y despues agregarlo a la etiqueta href

Answer (score 0):

```
$(function(){
  $('#a').attr('href','TuLink');
});
```

Comment: Podrias explicarle al op lo que hace este codigo? De esa manera podra permanecer como una respuesta valida.